# Execute upgrade-theme with coding

Tags: theme-development, updates, upgrade, xml-rpc

I'm executing some functions remotely from xmlprc with wordpress.

I would like to run upgrade-theme remotely for theme that I develop.

Assume that wp knows there is new version of theme. pre_set_site_transient_update_themes

What is the true function to call. And how to call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To whom it may need.

Here is the codes.

I hope it helps someone.

```
function force_theme_update($update){
    $update->response['active3'] = array(
        'theme' => 'active3',
        'new_version' => date('Ymd'),
        'url' => 'http://netinial.com/theme/theme.php',
        'package' => 'http://netinial.com/theme/theme.zip',
    );
    return $update;
}
if(current_user_can('manage_options')){ add_filter('site_transient_update_themes', 'force_theme_update'); }
```